# Get specific charters from raw string

Tags: javascript

I have a raw string like "**fsfsdfsdd [qwewqewe] sdfsdfdf sdfsd[sdf]**". How to get value from inside of [] this box and outside of [] this box. O/P **fsfsdfsdd,sdfsdfdf,sdfsd & qwewqewe,sdf** If it is possible to using JavaScript RegExp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
str = "fsfsdfsdd [qwewqewe] sdfsdfdf sdfsd[sdf]";
s = str.match(/\[(\w+?)\]/g);
s.forEach(i => console.log(i));
```

Without square brackets:

```
res = Array.from(str.matchAll(/\[(.+?)\]/g));
res.forEach(i => console.log(i[1]));
```

Comment: It's showing only inside of the box values

Comment: @vijay, I added a solution to exclude square brackets. Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "fsfsdfsdd [qwewqewe] sdfsdfdf sdfsd[sdf]";
let regex = /(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])/g;
let s1 = str.match(regex);      // strings in the brackets
let s2 = str.replace(regex, '').replace(/[[]]/g, '').replace(/\s/, '').split(' '); // strings outside the brackets

let result = [...s1, ...s2]

console.log(result)
```